# Convert to datetime format with hours, minutes and seconds separate

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I have this format of date time 2021-10-04 05:00:00.000Z.
I want in date , hh, mm, ss  separately.

How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime date=DateTime.parse("2021-10-04 05:00:00.000Z");
var mm=date.month;
var yy=date.year;
var hh=date.hour;
```

if you want format, use intl packeges
[pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
DateFormat df = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
df.format(DateTime.now())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void main() {
    var dt = DateTime.parse('2021-10-04 05:00:00.000Z');
    print(dt.year);
    print(dt.month);
    print(dt.hour);
    print(dt.minute);
    print(dt.second);
}
```

If you need another type of manipulations use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateFormat` to format the `DateTime`.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  DateTime dt = DateTime.parse('2021-10-04 05:00:00.000Z');
  String date = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dt);
  print(date);
  
  String time = DateFormat('hh:mm:ss').format(dt);
  print(time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. refer intl package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse("2021-10-04 05:00:00.000Z");
String yourDateTime = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss').format(dateTime);
```

If you want dd-MM-yyyy format try below code

```
String yourDateTime = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss').format(dateTime);
```

Your Widget:

```
 Text(
     yourDateTime,
 ),
```

Your result Screen-> [image]